# Generating set cardinality of subgroups of direct products

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-product

Given $G \le C_{a_1} \times C_{a_2} \times \ldots \times C_{a_n}$. Is it true that there exists a generating set $S$ that generates $G$ has at most $n$ elements?

Indeed, the statement above is correct when $n=1$. Since $G\le C_{a_1}$ and $C_{a_1}$ is a cyclic group, $G$ is also cyclic. It follows that there exists $S=\{x\}$ generating $G$.

Comment: It is a good first step to prove this statement for the case when all $a_i$ are degrees of a prime number $p$. In this case you can use the following observation. The number of generators of a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ is equal to the number $\log_p|G[p]|$ where $G[p]=\{x\in G\mid x^p=1\}$.

Comment: It follows from the standard result that a subgroup of a free abelian group of rank $n$ can be generated by at most $n$ elements.